# Click anywere to open new window with my link

Tags: hyperlink

Hello I have page with iframe and i want if  someone visits and click left mouse anywere 
Then open a new window with the link

I searched the internet and found nothing

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any (sane) reasons to do so, but you can try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onclick="popup()">
<body>

<h1>Click on this page!</h1>

<script>
function popup() {
    alert("I really hate popups, do you?");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```